# If statement for steps in a apache beam dataflow pipeline (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I was wondering if it is possible to have an if statement in a beam pipeline for enacting a different transform based on different scenarios. For example:

1) Make one of the input arguments backfill/regular and then based on that input argument it would decide whether to start with

```
(p 
            | fileio.MatchFiles(known_args.input_bucket)
            | fileio.ReadMatches()
            | beam.Map(lambda file: file.metadata.path, json.loads(file.read_utf8())))
```

or

```
p | beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input_file_name)
```

2) If the file name contains a certain country name (i.e. USA), call `TransformUSA(beam.DoFn)`, else call `TransformAllCountries(beam.DoFn)`

Sorry if this isn't a great question, i haven't seen this anywhere else and am trying to make my code modular instead of having separate pipelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely possible to have an if statement for your pipeline, but remember that things should be known at pipeline construction time. So, for instance:

```
with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  if known_args.backfill == True:
    input_pcoll = (p
                   | fileio.MatchFiles(known_args.input_bucket)
                   | fileio.ReadMatches()
                   | beam.Map(lambda file: file.read_utf8().split('\n'))
  else:
    input_pcoll = (p
                   | beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input_file_name)
```

And then, for your `TransformUSA`, you would do something like:

```
if 'USA' in known_args.input_file_name:
  next_pcoll = input_pcoll | beam.ParDo(TransformUSA())
else:
  next_pcoll = input_pcoll | beam.ParDo(TransformAllCountries())
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I will know shortly. There might be one caveat I have a question regarding, will accept it ASAP if it is perfect